# how to perform a groupby, sort, and concatenate strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas frame:

```
PK  Line    Text    Source
1   1       The     A
1   2       quick   A
1   3       brown   A
2   1       fox     A
2   2       jumped  A
3   1       over    A
3   2       the     A
3   3       lazy    A
4   1       yellow  A
5   1       dogs    A
5   2       sam     A
```

I need to get to:

```
PK  Text              Source
1   The quick brown   A
2   fox jumped        A
3   over the lazy     A
4   yellow            A
5   dogs sam          A
```

I've tried:

```
record.groupby('PK').apply(Lambda x: (' '.join(x)).sort_values('LINE', ascending))
```

but it seams I'm missing something.
How do I get this right?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be careful about capitalization. it's `lambda` not `Lambda` and the column key is `'Line'` not `'LINE'`. But there are other issues besides that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `groupby()` and aggregation:

```
df.groupby(['PK', 'Source'], as_index=False).Text.agg(' '.join)
```

You can add `sort_values('Line')` to make sure that the lines are in order, e.g.

```
(df.sort_values('Line')
        .groupby(['PK', 'Source'], as_index=False)
        .Text.agg(' '.join)
)
```

Output:

```
   PK Source             Text
0   1      A  The quick brown
1   2      A       fox jumped
2   3      A    over the lazy
3   4      A           yellow
4   5      A         dogs sam
```